# Running R code on linux in parallel on computing cluster

Tags: r, linux, parallel-processing

I've recently converted my windows R code to a Linux installation for running DEoptim on a function. On my windows system it all worked fine using:

```
ans <- DEoptim1(Calibrate,lower,upper,
                DEoptim.control(trace=TRUE,parallelType=1,parVAr=parVarnames3,
                                packages=c("hydromad","maptools","compiler","tcltk","raster")))
```

where the function 'Calibrate' consisted of multiple functions. On the windows system I simply downloaded the various packages needed into the R library. The option paralleType=1 ran the code across a series of cores.

However, now I want to put this code onto a Linux based computing cluster - the function 'Calibrate' works fine when stand alone, as does DEoptim if I want to run the code on one core. However, when I specify the parelleType=1, the code fails and returns:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
7 nodes produced errors; first error: there is no package called ‘raster’
```

This error is reproduced whatever package I try and recall, even though the

```
library(raster)
```

command worked fine and 'raster' is clearly shown as okay when I call all the libraries using:

```
library()
```

So, my gut feeling is, is that even though all the packages and libraries are loaded okay, it is because I have used a personal library and the packages element of DEoptim.control is looking in a different space. An example of how the packages were installed is below:

```
install.packages("/home/antony/R/Pkges/raster_2.4-15.tar.gz",rpeo=NULL,target="source",lib="/home/antony/R/library")
```

I also set the lib paths option as below:

```
.libPaths('/home/antony/R/library')
```

Has anybody any idea of what I am doing wrong and how to set the 'packages' option in DEoptim control so I can run DEoptim across multiple cores in parallel?

Many thanks, Antony

Comment: I've corrected a typo. Please confirm that the error was not caused by it.

Comment: The packages are not loaded on the workers. Depending on the parallel framework used by `DEoptim1`, there are different ways of fixing that. Possibly you need `clusterEvalQ` for calling `library` on all workers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I fixed this by loading onto the default libraries rather than my own library.  It appears that the workers need to look in the default library space.